# Objective C - checking if the tab is clicked from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have got two tabs which have the same direction to the same viewController , inside the viewController I want to check which tab is selected, I have this:

```
    -(void)btnProjects:(id)sender
{
    ProjectsCatsViewController *newview = [[ProjectsCatsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProjectsCatsViewController" bundle:nil];

    newview.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newview];
}

    -(void)btnNewUpdates:(id)sender
    {ProjectsCatsViewController *newview = [[ProjectsCatsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProjectsCatsViewController" bundle:nil];

    newview.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newview];
}
```

I want to do the filter inside a method in the

> ProjectsCatsViewController.m

[enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a boolean to NSUserDefaults then

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:true forKey:@"btn1Clicked"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Get this back in whatever controller you want.

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"btn1Clicked"]) {
    //do things
}else {
    //do things
}
```

Comment: I want to do the checking from another controller

Answer (score 0):

If it's UITabBarController

use

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex
```

If Its UITabBar use tags for each tab and use

```
tabBar.selectedItem.tag
```

Comment: I don't really get it, where should I put this ?

Comment: What do you mean by static tab. Have you used tab bar items, tab bar controller. Can you post you xib image or code so that I can better understand